# page redirect like in facebook

Tags: html

In facebook, if any photo of yours is tagged then you got informed in your mail.When you press link on the mail then

1. the page with tagged photo will be open if already logged in facebook
2. log in and will reach to tagged photo if not already logged in.

I am making pure html,jquery in frontend and asp.net services as backend. How can i achieve it. Suppose,
there are 3 page in my website: first-login_page.html, second-second_page.html, third-third_page.html.

Now the mail contains link to third page.

1. I have open third_page directly if already logged in.
2. I have to go to first page(login page) if not logged in. Then user enter username and password and press enter then will go to third page.

Can you give some idea on how can I do it.

Answer (score 1):

On 2nd & 3rd page ,use one **Hidden field**. Suppose some one login then store some **Token Key** or anything in Hidden field.... Now someone come via link which is sent in email... By **javascript/jQuery** check that **Hidden field** is **NULL** or not, also set logic... Check if **Hidden field** have valid value or not. From this you can check if user is already **Logged In** or not.... Suppose he is not login then redirect on login page else go ahead....

Hope you are familiar with code syntax..Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

On the third_page, you check if the user has logged in or not

if the user hasn't logged in, redirect the user to login page